# how to insert record with a null in Cakephp3 composite primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

my received_po_details table has 3 primary key received_po_id, product_id, product_serial.
Sometimes the product_serial has value and sometimes nothing

cakephp3 is not allowing me to insert records if the product_serial is empty

**error**

> Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got
>   (12, 1, ), expecting (received_po_id, product_id, product_serial)

sql table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `received_po_details` (
  `received_po_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_serial` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (received_po_id, product_id, product_serial),
  FOREIGN KEY received_po_key (received_po_id) REFERENCES received_pos(id),
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),
  UNIQUE KEY received_po_detail_key (received_po_id, product_id, product_serial)
);
```

note that product_serial is just a value. Its not a foreign key

entity - receivedPoDetail.php

```
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'received_po_id' => true,
    'product_id' => true,
    'product_serial' => true,
];
```

controller

```
$receivedPo = $this->ReceivedPos->patchEntity($receivedPo, $this->request->data);
```

request data print

```
Array
(
    [purchase_order_id] => 1
    [depot_id] => 1
    [prepared_by_id] => 
    [approved_by_id] => 
    [date_registration] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2016
            [month] => 05
            [day] => 20
            [hour] => 03
            [minute] => 45
        )

    [comment] => 
    [received_po_status_id] => 2
    [received_po_details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [quantity_received] => 100
                    [product_serial] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [quantity_received] => 1
                    [product_serial] => random_serial_here
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [quantity_received] => 300
                    [product_serial] => 
                )

        )

)
```

thanks

Comment: Its now working by editing my ReceivedPoDetailsTable initialize method primarykey from $this->primaryKey(['received_po_id', 'product_id', 'product_serial']); to $this->primaryKey(['received_po_id', 'product_id']); and its now working. Also added $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['received_po_id', 'product_id', 'product_serial'])) at buildRules method. 

But idk if this is the correct solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you sould set the default value of `product_serial` to `null`
It should be  like this ..

```
  `product_serial` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```